# allowing product with custom options as bundled item

Tags: product, attributes, bundled-product, attribute-set

when i am trying to add product as bundled items it does not shows product with custom option , how can i solve this issue

below is my case

```
1: i have different products attribute sets : ring, pendant ,earrings
2: ring can be in multiple size : 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 with same price for all
3: so i thought of using custom drop down option in add products
4: now same product does not appears while adding bundled items.
```

ways to solve it

```
1: can i do something so product with custom options can also be shown while adding bundled items
2: is there way to add drop down attributes to products other that configurable and custom option that will also be supported by bundled items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done out of the box.

I found following two extension. That seams to let you build a bundle items with custom options.

1. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dependent-custom-options-bundle.html
2. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bundle-products-custom-options.html

I haven't tested it.

Hope this will help you

Comment: these two are of now use : check if u can do it